Object 'output' not found in R shiny dashboard
I'm constantly getting this error:
Quitting from lines 30-65 [unnamed-chunk-3] (Dashboard.qmd)
Error:
! object 'output' not found
Execution halted
I'm using the following code:
#| context: server
#| include: false

approval <- reactive({asylum_decisions %>%
mutate(approved=
     dec_recognized+dec_other) %>%
filter(year=c("2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021","2022"))
left_join(countries_2, join_by(coo_name)) %>%
group_by(year,input$unhcr_region)

})

output$data <- renderTable({approval})

output$plot <- renderPlot({
p <- ggplot(approval,
   aes(x = year,
       y = approved,
       fill = approved)) +
    geom_col() +
    theme_unhcr()
 })


Welcome to SO! Have you included server: shiny in the YAML of your quarto document? If that does not fix your issue please provide a minimal reproducible example containing a minimal but complete Qmd and a snippet of your input data if required (best shared using dput()) or use some fake data or a built-in dataset.

Try renderTable({approval()}).  You are missing ()

We would need to see more of your setup to be entirely sure but from what you posted one possible solution is in the  comments as provided by @YBS.
When using a previously created reactive variable you need the format is reactive_var().
Without the () it will not work.
#| context: server
#| include: false

approval <- reactive({asylum_decisions %>%
mutate(approved=
     dec_recognized+dec_other) %>%
filter(year=c("2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021","2022"))
left_join(countries_2, join_by(coo_name)) %>%
group_by(year,input$unhcr_region)

})

output$data <- renderTable({approval()})

output$plot <- renderPlot({
p <- ggplot(approval(),
   aes(x = year,
       y = approved,
       fill = approved)) +
    geom_col() +
    theme_unhcr()
 })

